# Appenders while migration from log4j1.2.x to log4j 2

Tags: log4j2

We are working on adding custom level logging into our logger (which is currently log4j 1.2.x) and understood that this functionality is supported since log4j 2.

Thus we are planning to migrate from log4j 1.2.x to log4j2 version. However, our logger application is completely dependent on the log4j 1.2.x appenders where we directly extend / inherit appender classes like FileAppender etc. Right the bridge dont have support for the individual appenders and we are using the appenders in our application to log data.

Is there any way that those classes (which are dependent on FileAppender) can be readily migrated, because I dont see much information in internet / apache.org to get the internals.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it seems to me you have 2 options - either take the time to examine the new log4j2 appenders and extend them as you extended the log4j1 appenders or try to find a way to use the standard appenders bundled with log4j2. You might start with the log4j2 manual - the section titled [Extending Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html)